# How do I add line break to .textContent?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I have checked multiple other questions and none of them seemed to work. And no, I would not like to use .innerHTML because that would make it not work.
Heres my code:

```
generation.textContent=
 "<!DOCTYPE html>X"+
 "<html>"+
  "<head>"+
   "<style>"+
    cinput+
   "<\/style>"+
  "<\/head>"+
  "<body>"+
   hinput+
   "<script>"+
    jinput+
   "<\/script>"+
  "<\/body>"+
 "<\/html>";
```

After each plus sign/line there needs to be a linebreak.

Comment: Use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of string concatenation, and set `white-space: pre` to the element showing `textContent`.

Comment: @Yogi I have tried that, but that didn't work.